# $ character in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the objective of placing the $ symbol after the 'add' and 'tab' in the activeKey and the tab respectively?

```css
addNum=0;
onAdd=()=> {
  this.addNum++;
  let panes=Array.from(this.state.panes);
  let activeKey=`add$ {
    this.addNum
  }
  `;
  let tabObj= {
    key: activeKey,
    tab: `tab$ {
      this.addNum
    }
    `,
    closable: true,
  }
  ;
  panes.push(tabObj);
  this.setState( {
    panes, activeKey: activeKey
  }
  );
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: That seems very weirdly formatted, I think they're trying to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` symbol in JavaScript is used for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Literals are frequently used for string interpolation. Inside the literal, you can use JavaScript code to calculate the final value to be rendered.

With concatenation you would do something like this:

```
let first_name = 'Justin', last_name = 'Lim';

console.log(first_name + ' ' + last_name); // Justin Lim
```

With template literals, you can do it in a less verbose way. Like this:

```
let first_name = 'Justin', last_name = 'Lim';

console.log(`${first_name} ${last_name}`); // Justin Lim
```

Another example of literal's usage:

```
let age = 25;

console.log(`I'm ${age} years old!`); // I'm 25 years old!
```

In your example, code is not well formatted, but the final goal would be for `activeKey` to get the value `add NUMBER`, where number would be the value of `this.addNum`.

If the value for `this.addNum` was 1, the `activeKey` variable would get the value `add 1`, and so on.